# What docking station for MacBook Pro 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation

I'm looking for a docking station to connect my MacBook Pro to Logitech Webcam with a USB-C cable and a Projector with an HDMI cable.

My MacBook Pro is (13-inch, Mid 2012), macOS 10.15.7. I could not find anything compatible with my MacBook pro. Could anyone give me some help with what docking station or adaptor I should get, please?

Comment: It's unlikely you'll find a docking station for a 10 year old Mac. You'll need a mini-display port to HDMI adapter for your monitor and an adapter to plug your USB-C webcam into a USB-A port. So a USB-C female to USB-A adaptor, if such a beast exists.

Comment: Your problem is that anything that has Thunderbolt 2 won't have USB-C, and vice versa. Apple sells a TB2 to TB3 adaptor, but it's for a TB2 plug going into a TB3 socket, not the other way round.